# Add namespace for form_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I'm using `bootstrap_form` gem for form generating in Rails. In my form view, I am using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_tag url: 'metafields' do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :owner_id, value: params[:owner_id] %>
    <%= f.text_field :namespace, placeholder: 'Namespace of metafield' %>
    <%= f.text_field :key, placeholder: 'Key of metafield' %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Description about metafield' %>
    <%= f.select :type, [['String', 'string']], class: 'selectpicker' %>
  <% end %>
```

Is there a way to submit this form with params including prefix namespace like `params[:metafield][:owner_id]`.

When I tried with

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: 'metafields', namespace: 'metafield' do |f| %>
```

It generates below input, which is not what I want

```
<input placeholder="Key of metafield" name="key" id="metafield_key" class="form-control" type="text" kl_vkbd_parsed="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quyetdc's answer is a way to go unless you have dynamic forms, here is a cleaner way

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_tag url: 'metafields' do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :metafield do |mf| %>
      <%= mf.hidden_field :owner_id, value: params[:owner_id] %>
      <%= mf.text_field :namespace, placeholder: 'Namespace of metafield' %>
      <%= mf.text_field :key, placeholder: 'Key of metafield' %>
      <%= mf.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Description about metafield' %>
      <%= mf.select :type, [['String', 'string']], class: 'selectpicker' %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As from [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag), `form_tag` does not support namespace like `form_for`. Thus, I found a workaround as below, which generate correct `name` for input as if we use `form_for`

```
    <%= bootstrap_form_tag url: 'metafields' do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :owner_id, value: @owner_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :owner_class, value: @owner_class %>
      <%= f.text_field :'metafield[namespace]', label: 'Namespace', placeholder: 'Namespace of metafield' %>
      <%= f.text_field :'metafield[key]',label: 'Key', placeholder: 'Key of metafield' %>
      <%= f.text_field :'metafield[value]',label: 'Value', placeholder: 'Key of metafield' %>
      <%= f.select :'metafield[value_type]', [['String', 'string']], label: 'Type', class: 'selectpicker' %>
      <%= f.text_area :'metafield[description]', label: 'Description', placeholder: 'Description about metafield' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-outline-dark float-right' %>
    <% end %>
```